# destroy object on parse.com php

Tags: php, parse-platform, destroy

Good day Every one, please I have a problem with my parse.com application I'm working with PHP (codeIgniter as a framework) and I can't destroy the object I created. here is my code (simple PHP page);

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
session_start();
\Parse\ParseClient::initialize( 'secret', 'secret', 'secret' );
\Parse\ParseClient::setServerURL('http://localhost:1337/parse');
use Parse\ParseObject;
use Parse\ParseQuery;
use Parse\ParseACL;
use Parse\ParsePush;
use Parse\ParseUser;
use Parse\ParseInstallation;
use Parse\ParseException;
use Parse\ParseAnalytics;
use Parse\ParseFile;
use Parse\ParseCloud;
use Parse\ParseClient;
$gamescore = new ParseObject('GameScore');
$gamescore->destroy();
```

Comment: You should provide the error messages. I do not write php, but in this case, you have not destroy anything. Destroy is to delete from db. You are just create a object, and delete it without save it to db.

Answer (score 0):

there is no error in my code. it just don't work like that. I realized that Classes can't be deleted by code you must deleted from the dashboard.
Thank you